# Getting remainding lines in a CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a script here which will get all the lines in a csv and insert them into a database (FileMaker to be exact), and I want it to count to 100 lines, break the loop, then tell me the remainding lines which are left. My code is below, Please see and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public function insertTimesheet() {


    //Get the public variables
    $fm = $this->fm;
    $timesheet = $this->data['timesheets'];
    $total = count($timesheet);
    $fm = $this->fm;

    $count = 0;
    $total = count($timesheet);

    //Loop through the data items in the array
    foreach ($timesheet as $element) {

        //Checks each key value in the array
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($timesheet); ++$i) {

            if($i == 100){
                printf('%d Timesheets added', $i);
                break;

                // Return which timesheets have not been added //
            }

            //Prevents duplicate entries
            $count++;
            //Manually add some data to the array
            $timesheet[$i]['Created_By_Staff_ID']   = $_SESSION["user"]->staff_id;
            $timesheet[$i]['Key_Staff_ID']          = $_SESSION["user"]->staff_id;
            $timesheet[$i]['Timesheet_Type']        = 'CSV_UPLOAD';
            $timesheet[$i]['Resource_ID']           = 'N/A At this time [CSV UPLOAD]';

            //Convert the dates to USA dates (FileMaker Format)
            $timesheet[$i]['Date_From']             = $this->convertDate($timesheet[$i]['Date_From']);
            $timesheet[$i]['Date_To']               = $this->convertDate($timesheet[$i]['Date_To']);

            //Insert the data into the Database
            $addReq = & $fm->createRecord('Web_Staff_Timesheet', $timesheet[$i]);
            $result = $addReq->commit();

            //Checks for filemaker errors
            if (!FileMaker::isError($result)) {
                $return['error'] = false;
                $return['msg'] = 'Timesheet added successfully';
                $strOut = sprintf('<br />Working on %d of %d timesheets', $count, $total);
                //return true;
            } else {
                $return['error'] = true;
                $return['errorCode'] = $result->code;
                $return['msg'] = 'Unable to add Timesheet';
                $strOut = sprintf('<br />Sorry, we could not add your time sheet, FileMaker Produced this error: %s <br /> Failed to insert the following timesheets [Line number]: ', $return['errorCode'], $count);
                return false;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    //Clear the array to prevent duplicates
    unset($timesheet, $element, $this->data);
    return $strOut;
}
```

Comment: Does `print count($timesheet) - 100;` not do it for you?

Comment: no, sorry I want the data within those lines, not just the number of lines. Sorry if I was unclear on that.

Comment: could you please show the sample data in $timesheet array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI guys, I've sorted it out now. Thanks for your time anyways!